# In C bits, multiply by 3 and divide by 16

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, bit, puzzle

A buddy of mine had these puzzles and this is one that is eluding me. Here is the problem, you are given a number and you want to return that number times 3 and divided by 16 rounding towards 0. Should be easy. The catch? You can only use the ! ~ & ^ | + << >> operators and of them only a combination of 12.

```
int mult(int x){
    //some code here...
return y;
}
```

My attempt at it has been:

```
    int hold = x + x + x;
    int hold1 = 8;
    hold1 = hold1 & hold;
    hold1 = hold1 >> 3;
    hold = hold >> 4;
    hold = hold + hold1;
    return hold;
```

But that doesn't seem to be working. I think I have a problem of losing bits but I can't seem to come up with a way of saving them. Another perspective would be nice. Just to add, you also can only use variables of type int and no loops, if statements or function calls may be used.

Right now I have the number 0xfffffff. It is supposed to return 0x2ffffff but it is returning 0x3000000.

Comment: You meant to say `eluding`.

Comment: you wouldn't want to multiply 0xffffffff by 3, first divide then multiply. or its going to overflow. and you need to store it in a unsinged long

Comment: @tesseract That would loose you important precision, for example: `int(3*15/16) = 2`, but `int(15/16)*3 = 0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this question you need to worry about the lost bits before your division (obviously).
Essentially, if it is negative then you want to add 15 after you multiply by 3. A simple `if` statement (using your operators) should suffice.

I am not going to give you the code but a step by step would look like,

```
x = x*3
```

get the sign and store it in variable foo.

have another variable hold x + 15;

Set up an if statement so that if x is negative it uses that added 15 and if not then it uses the regular number (times 3 which we did above).

Then divide by 16 which you already showed you know how to do. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work (as long as no overflow occurs):

```
((num<<2)+~num+1)>>4
```

Try this JavaScript code, run in console:

```
for (var num = -128; num <= 128; ++num) {
  var a = Math.floor(num * 3 / 16);
  var b = ((num<<2)+~num+1)>>4;
  console.log(
    "Input:", num,
    "Regular math:", a,
    "Bit math:", b,
    "Equal: ", a===b
  );
}
```

Comment: just to give an example of one that doesnt work. -268435457[0xefffffff])gives -50331649[0xfcffffff] it should be -50331648[0xfd000000].

Comment: Yes, caused by overflow, as `0xefffffff << 2` overflows the JavaScript 32 bit integer type, which is used when bit math is used. You didn't specify any requirements on the numbers which is why I added the note about overflow.

Comment: Overflow is what is giving me the problem. Otherwise I could just do x + x + x then << 4. But thank you for trying.

Comment: So how does this help? All you've done is rewrite `x + x + x` into the moral equivalent of `x * 4 - x`. That doesn't fix anything.

Comment: I see now that I missed the "round towards zero" part. I'm using round down here instead, which is not per your request. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is first divide by 4 then add 3 times then again devide by 4.

```
3*x/16=(x/4+x/4+x/4)/4
```

with this logic the program can be

```
main()
{
   int x=0xefffffff;
   int y;
   printf("%x",x);
   y=x&(0x80000000);
   y=y>>31;
   x=(y&(~x+1))+(~y&(x));
   x=x>>2;
   x=x&(0x3fffffff);
   x=x+x+x;
   x=x>>2;
   x=x&(0x3fffffff);
    x=(y&(~x+1))+(~y&(x));
   printf("\n%x %d",x,x);
}
```

AND with 0x3fffffff to make msb's zero. it'l even convert numbers to positive.
This uses 2's complement of negative numbers. with direct methods to divide there will be loss of bit accuracy for negative numbers. so use this work arround of converting -ve to +ve number then perform division operations.

Comment: Im not 100% sure I'm following your solution. For one thing I dont have to make it positive. But just as a reference I can give you an example. mult(-268435457[0xefffffff]) gives 754974719[0x2cffffff] when it should be -50331648[0xfd000000].

Comment: @Shaw you mentioned in question that 0xffffffff gets the value 0x2ffffff. for that you considered 0xffffffff as what value in decimal?

Comment: 268435455. It is only 7 f's

Comment: @Shaw ok. i made a small change to preserve the sign bit. i think it'll work fine now.

Comment: im not sure it was just the sign.
mult(-268435457[0xefffffff]) gives 754974719[0x2cffffff] it should be -50331648[0xfd000000]

Comment: @Shaw ya the problem was not sign bit. it was because of 2's complement representation of -ve numbers. check this solution this logic works for all cases.

Comment: hmm, it seems to work with a lot of cases. But when I ran through with x = 268435451[0xffffffb]. I get 50331646[0x2fffffe] when it should be 50331647[0x2ffffff]. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Oh, it also goes above the 12 allotted ops. I realize this is annoying but I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

### The Maths

When you divide a positive integer `n` by 16, you get a positive integer quotient `k` and a remainder `c < 16`:

```
    (n/16) = k + (c/16).
```

(Or simply apply the Euclidan algorithm.) The question asks for multiplication by `3/16`, so multiply by 3

```
    (n/16) * 3 = 3k + (c/16) * 3.
```

The number `k` is an integer, so the part `3k` is still a whole number. However, `int` arithmetic rounds down, so the second term may lose precision if you divide first, And since `c < 16`, you can safely multiply first without overflowing (assuming `sizeof(int) >= 7`). So the algorithm design can be

```
    (3n/16) = 3k + (3c/16).
```

### The design

- The integer `k` is simply `n/16` rounded down towards 0. So `k` can be found by applying a single `AND` operation. Two further operations will give `3k`. Operation count: 3.
- The remainder  `c` can also be found using an `AND` operation (with the missing bits). Multiplication by 3 uses two more operations. And shifts finishes the division. Operation count: 4.
- Add them together gives you the final answer.

Total operation count: 8.

### Negatives

The above algorithm uses shift operations. It may not work well on negatives. However, assuming two's complement, the sign of `n` is stored in a sign bit. It can be removed beforing applying the algorithm and reapplied on the answer.

- To find and store the sign of `n`, a single `AND` is sufficient.
- To remove this sign, `OR` can be used.
- Apply the above algorithm.
- To restore the sign bit, Use a final `OR` operation on the algorithm output with the stored sign bit.

This brings the final operation count up to 11.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the C99 standard states in section section 6.5.7 that right shifts of signed negative integer invokes implementation-defined behavior. Under the provisions that `int` is comprised of 32 bits and that right shifting of signed integers maps to an arithmetic shift instruction, the following code works for all `int` inputs. A fully portable solution that also fulfills the requirements set out in the question may be possible, but I cannot think of one right now.

My basic idea is to split the number into high and low bits to prevent intermediate overflow. The high bits are divided by 16 first (this is an exact operation), then multiplied by three. The low bits are first multiplied by three, then divided by 16. Since arithmetic right shift rounds towards negative infinity instead of towards zero like integer division, a correction needs to be applied to the right shift for negative numbers. For a right shift by N, one needs to add 2<sup>N</sup>-1 prior to the shift if the number to be shifted is negative.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ref (int a)
{
  long long int t = ((long long int)a * 3) / 16;
  return (int)t;
}

int main (void)
{
  int a, t, r, c, res;
  a = 0;
  do {
    t = a >> 4;         /* high order bits */
    r = a & 0xf;        /* low order bits */
    c = (a >> 31) & 15; /* shift correction. Portable alternative: (a < 0) ? 15 : 0 */
    res = t + t + t + ((r + r + r + c) >> 4);
    if (res != ref(a)) {
      printf ("!!!! error a=%08x  res=%08x  ref=%08x\n", a, res, ref(a));
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    a++;
  } while (a);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```