# How to multiply by three sixteenths

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I need to multiply a number by 3/16, **rounding to zero** using only bitwise operations such as  `! ~ & ^ | + << >>`. So far I have the following, the only problem is it doesn't work when the number is negative, it always rounds down rather than to zero. I know there should be bitwise if statement that if x is negative then add 15. But I dont know how to implement it, any help is appreciated.

```
int ezThreeSixteenths(int x) {
    int times_two = x << 1;
    int times_three = times_two + x;
    int divide_eight = times_three >> 4;
    int a = 0b11111111;
    int a1 = a << 8;
    int a2 = a << 16;
    int a3 = 0b11111 << 24;
    int mask = a | a1 | a2 | a3;
    int final = divide_eight & mask;
    return final;
}
```

Comment: `>> 4` doesn't divide by 8, it divides by 16. Note that bit shifting works best for unsigned integers. Right shifting signed numbers is implementation-defined (i.e. the sign bit may be kept or it may not).

Comment: A non-negative int `&`-ed with a bitmask where only the sign bit is `1` produces `0`.

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077554/in-c-bits-multiply-by-3-and-divide-by-16/22078232#22078232)

Comment: This is an impossible endeavor, since _"If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined"_. So while it might be possible to get it "working", it won't necessarily work on any other compiler or even on a different version of the same compiler. Don't mix shifts with signed values.

Comment: Friend of yours? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077554/in-c-bits-multiply-by-3-and-divide-by-16

Comment: If x is negative add 15 can be done like this:

x += ((((unsigned)x >> 27) & 0xF) - 1);

or like this using an arithmetic shift:

x += (x >> 31) & 0xF;

Comment: `0b11111`? That's not C. No "binary" constants in C.

Comment: @Jens, not C, but I believe there is an extension in GCC.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function that you are satisfied works when it's positive, test the MSB to detect a negative bit, if so take the two's complement (you don't say whether you can use `-` as well as `+` but you can use `^` and `+`), run your function, then take the two's complement again.

Answer (score 0):

Use twos complement to convert a negative number to a positive number. Then when you're done convert the positive number back to a negative one?